# Android setter of String array

Tags: android, arrays

I've got simple setter and getter of string array. I want to use setter to put some retrieved json info + same text to array. When I use this code:

```
met.setPlacepic(new String[]{"http://dfsdfsdfsf/" + json.getString("source")});
```

it looks like setter put only one string to array, despite there is many more data.

Declaration is simple:

```
public String[] placepic
```

and the setter is also simple:

```
public void setPlacepic(String[] placepic) {
        this.placepic = placepic;
}
```

Does anybody know the reason of this?

Comment: It did put one string because you only gave one string. What did you expect?

Comment: This is not an Android question but more about a question about Java's arrays. Have a look at and you'll find out how they work: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: this method is inside of loop which retrevie more than one string

Comment: So what? what you do in each iteration is provide a new array to your `setPlacepic()`. Do you want to add to it instead?

Comment: i want do store every data in one array, please help i'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of strings is fixed (you know exactly how many element you would have in the array), then you could use String Arrays:

```
String[] placepic = new String[20]; //20 strings
//Then, in your loop:
placepic[i] = yourData;
```

If you do NOT know how many strings in your data, You should use List:

```
List<String> placepicList= new ArrayList<String>();
//Then, in your loop:
placepicList.add(yourData);
//Then after the loop, you get the array
String[] placepic = placepicList.toArray(new String[placepicList.size()]);
```